# Passing port number to html after it is created

Tags: javascript, html

The process I'm doing is write an html file, and some time in the future open a local server, that searches for an open port, so I only know the port that the server is listening to after the html is created. Is there any way to pass the port number to the html page when opening it?

I thought about writing the port number into a file and somehow use javascript to read the file, but I understand that because of security restrictions, I can't read a file on the client-side into a javascript variable.

Comment: Why don't you edit the html file ?

Comment: Use relative URLs? Or isn't this about URLs? I think your question is a bit unclear. What do you mean by 'passing the port to HTML'?

Comment: I can't edit the html after it's created because other users are going to use it, and what I'm looking for is that each one will have a local server, so actually there are going to be a few open ports in parallel.

Comment: You'd probably have to do some ajax polling of the server to retrieve the port number.

Comment: I thought of maybe creating a temporary html file and somehow make there a global variable with the port num, and then open the original html and use that global variable (which means actually opening two tabs in my browser). Do you think it's possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could go with the javascript [window.postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.postMessage) method here. This allows you to safely pass messages across origins. Once you have the port, use this to pass it on to the initial html.

EDIT:

Let me clarify my answer a bit more.

With the postMessage method, it is possible to send messages between tabs or windows. So here is how it can work for you.

1. User opens your HTML file, which attaches a listener for a message from another page.
   eg:

   `window.addEventListener("message", receiveMessage, false);`
2. Once you have your port, all you need to do is, pass the port in the postMessage method.
   eg:

   `popup.postMessage("8080", "http://domainOfFirstHTML.file");`

The only challenge I see in this approach is the 2nd step. But as it seems to be possible for your to write a file, Im guessing you could open another HTML file, that posts the message to the first HTML and closes itself.

Comment: I think that might work. I also thought about local storage or cookies, again with an HTML that opens itself and closes. What do you think?

Comment: I have not played with local storage, but it should work too. Your first HTML file would listen to [the storage event](http://dev.w3.org/html5/webstorage/#localStorageEvent), which would be fired by a second HTML once the port is known. The concept is the same its just that we use different methods to pass the data

Comment: Thanks. I think I'll try and use local storage or cookies.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly:

A. some service writes server port into HTML file.

B. later you wan't to read that port and use it (in same HTML)?

If so - it can be done with javascript **location** object (location.port) - that is read from html file (for example from some div's ID (...id="80"...)

Comment: Actually it's the other way, first the html is created, and after that the server is opened, so when I create the html file, I don't know yet the port.
I can give an example: the first html file is only a click button, and my intention is that when I click on the button, I'll contact the local server, and again, when I created the html, I still don't know the port.

Comment: Right, tnx, so if using some server-side is ok I would do it with PHP (same way as with JavaScript - using PHP's DOM manipulator (if editing HTML is not an option)) or maybe node.js...